# Pop-under is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

Here's pop-under code that I found on google. I need to get a form in pop-under. The code shows a pop-under on Firefox but it gives pop-up in Chrome. As I don't understand it so can someone do all the thinking for me? Thanks for your great support and help.

Here is the Code Below:

The main Function

```
function jsPopunder(sUrl, sName, sWidth, sHeight) {
if (typeof(sName) === null || sName === '') sName = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

sWidth = (sWidth || screen.width);
sHeight = (sHeight || screen.height);
sHeight = sHeight - 122;

var sOptions = 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,statusbar=yes,menubar=no,resizable=1,width=' + sWidth.toString() + ',height=' + sHeight.toString() + ',screenX=0,screenY=0,left=0,top=0';

// create pop-up from parent context
var _parent = (top != self && typeof(top.document.location.toString()) === 'string') ? top : self;
var popunder = _parent.window.open(sUrl, sName, sOptions);
if (popunder) {
    popunder.blur();
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') === -1) {
        popunder.params = {
            url: sUrl
        };
        (function(e) {
            with(e) {
                if (typeof window.mozPaintCount != 'undefined' || typeof navigator.webkitGetUserMedia === "function") {
                    try {
                        var poltergeist = document.createElement('a');
                        poltergeist.href = "javascript:window.open('about:blank').close();document.body.removeChild(poltergeist)";
                        document.body.appendChild(poltergeist).click();
                    } catch (err) {}
                }
            }
        })(popunder);
    }
    window.focus();
    try {
        opener.window.focus();
    } catch (err) {}
}
}
```

The Snippet for getting pop-under

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var opened = false;
    console.log( "ready!" );

    $('a').attr("href", "link will go here"); 
    $('a').click(function(){
      console.log( "test!" );
        if (!opened) {
        jsPopunder('link will go here');
        opened = true;
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: *"The code shows a pop-under on Firefox but it gives pop-up in Chrome."* Good! Too bad about Firefox though. Pop-unders are evil. Don't be evil. :-)

Comment: Is there any solution?